# Facebook login keeps failing

Tags: android, facebook

Before starting, a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332909/cancel-url-url-is-not-correctly-formatted) was asked recently, but I was facing a couple of other issues, and wanted to add some context.

Basically, off late, I witnessed that the login with Facebook feature in my Android app would keep failing for new users (who hadn't authorized the app before). However, this wasn't a recurring issue, so I sort of ignored it. But now this seems to be happening far too regularly.

I am absolutely sure that no changes were made in the app's settings locally or with the FB settings page.

There are 2 variants of the error -

a simple "Error occurred. Try again." And another which gives a much more detailed output.

[image] >>>>>[image]

However, I'm not sure of what changes do I need to make, if any. Would really appreciate any help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the cancel URL you are using? Maybe it contains invalid characters. An urlEncode could help.

Comment: actually, I couldn't even figure out where in the Facebook app settings I can specify the `cancel_url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/280811108698311) for this had been filed, and it has been closed now.

Answer (score 1):

In your facebook developer account try going to your application settings-> advanced and select Native/Desktop in Authentication. This should remove at least the first error.

I created a new application today and I'm also facing the second error. But for the older projects it works.

Comment: just did that - so far still facing the same issue. though i believe it's supposed to take some time before it kicks in. will update tomorrow how this went.

Comment: so even after a day, it's still the same. i changed the Facebook setting for the app - made it *Native/Desktop* in Authentication - but both the errors still persist.

Comment: bug has been filed here - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/463219573709230?browse=search_504eebc4870034046460825